# Script cambio categoría de elemento de lista en Sitio de SharePoint 2013

Tags: script, sharepoint

Tengo un sitio en SharePoint 2013 que contiene una libreria con una lista, esta lista contiene post categorizados, pero la categorización se realizó erroneamente.

Estoy intentado realizar un Script y ejecutarlo en el Shell de Administración de Sharepoint pero la consola devuelve constantementeel siguiente error:

```
Get-SPweb: Cannot fint an SPweb object with Id or URl:"www.companyname.domain/companyname/blog/Lists/libraryname"
```

Script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Site URL and List names
$SiteURL = "http://www.nnameofcompany.es/blog/Lists/Library"
$ListName = "Name of List"
$FieldName="Category" 

#Get site and List objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
if($web -ne $null)
{
   $List = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

   if($List -ne $null)
   {   
        #Get all List items
        $ListItems = $list.Items
         
        #Iterate through each item
        Foreach($item in $ListItems)
        {
            #Get the real category throug the URL
            $Separator="/"
            $NewCategory=$Item["Url"].Split($Separator,2)

            #To update Category Field with the Real Category,
            $item[$FieldName]= $NewCategory;
 
            #sharepoint powershell update all items in list
            $item.update()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good: *You know english*, Bad: *You are at [es.so]*, please translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Por otro lado, el código como texto, y [no como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Saludos

Comment: También traduce el título por favor